# Change sprite on mouseover

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite, gameobject

I have a sprite that acts as a button in the main menu of my game. It has a box collider, and I use `OnMouseDown()` to register clicks of the button.

I want to make the sprite change when my mouse rolls over the button. I know I can do stuff using the function `OnMouseOver()` but how do I switch between 2 sprites completely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don’t need to use two sprites and switch between them. Just use an effect like this one:

```cs
void OnMouseOver()
{
    transform.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite.color = "your new color for clicking effect";
    transform.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite.localScale -= new Vector3(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f);
}
```

and get back all this proccess in `OnMouseExit`. Or, if you still want to change sprite, you can change it like so:

```cs
Sprite sprite;
Sprite highlightSprite;

void OnMouseOver()
{
    transform.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = highlightSprite;
}

void OnMouseExit()
{
    transform.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = sprite;
}
```

and change back in `OnMouseExit`.

Comment: This works well. However what if you had a blue sprite that you created in say, photoshop? Would `sprite.color` still change the colour of the sprite?

Comment: it changes but i.e. when you set color to red, it becames blue+red I think. not became color exactly you set.

Answer (score 1):

put the mouse functions onto an empty parent `GameObject`, and parent it to all of the sprites you want, then just enable/disable them via the parent

Answer (score 1):

Other options:

- Use worldspace UI button instead (then you can use the built-in spriteswap transition and other button methods : http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-SelectableTransition.html )
- Add public Sprite variable and assign mouseover sprite to that, then in OnMouseOver() use that sprite image in your button sprite. (and revert back to original sprite on mouse out)
- Could also use Mecanim animation, OnMouseOver() toggle to another animation (which only has 1 frame)